# Django tests not finding my tests

Tags: django, django-tests

When I run tests, django runs 0 tests. This is my project structure:

```
manage.py
- app/
  - main_app/
    - test/
       - tests_v1.py
       - tests_v2.py
```

I use this command:

```
python manage.py test --pattern="tests_v*.py"
```

Django runs 0 tests in 0 seconds. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you forget the `.py` extension on tests_v1 and tests_v2 files?

Comment: @Pawamoy just an error writing the SO question. Corrected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` file inside `test` directory. Then import all inside it like

In `__init__.py`

```
from tests_v1 import *
from tests_v2 import *
```

**Note**

Name `tests_v1` as `tests_v1.py`

Comment: django's test runner will discover tests based on file name pattern, so no need to import in `__init__.py`

Comment: For pattern also like `main_app.test.tests_v1` it needs __init__.py

Comment: Yes, file `__init__.py` is required, but not imports in it.

Comment: Import not required, but it will discover all tasks with using pattern as "test", i guess

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem today. It turns out that my problem was two-fold.

1. I forgot to remove the tests.py from my app folder after I've created my tests folder.
2. I didn't add `__init__.py` which [makes my directory a package.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

It took me a lot of time so I am writing a response just in case someone else faced the same problem. I was able to make my test work once I did the following.

**Solution:**

1. Remove tests.py under the app folder.
2. Add `__init__.py` inside my test folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the folder where the tests are found. Try this:

```
python manage.py test app.mainapp.test
```

Comment: It returns this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test' .

Answer (score 1):

Ensure to prefix all test cases (methods) with "test". e.g.

```
def test_create_cycles_with_valid_data(self):
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me and the answer has to do with `__init__.py`, however, it depends on how you have structured your project, in my case, I had something like this:

```
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations/
│   │   ├── test/
│   │   │   ├── test_models.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations/
│   │   ├── test.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── views.py
    .
    .
    .
```

Getting:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

The solution to this was to add `__init__.py` inside the tests folder and inside the apps folder. The structure is as follows:

```
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py **
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations/
│   │   ├── test/
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py **
│   │   │   ├── test_models.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   ├── app2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations/
│   │   ├── test.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   ├── app2
    .
    .
    .
```

I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while running

```
python manage.py test --keepdb app.test
```

it was not finding any test. Then I decided to run it once without "keepdb" and it found all the test. Afterwards I could run again with "keepdb". No idea why this worked.

Answer (score -2):

```
1) `python ./manage.py test appname.tests_v1.classname.function_name`

2) Else 

`pip install nose pinocchio django_nose`

add below line in settings.py 

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-spec', '--spec-color']  

then run 

`python manage.py test`
```

ref : http://hentzia.com/blog/bdd-with-python.html

Comment: Nose might be a cool thing, but this just works around the problem and does not address it. Adding additional dependencies to a project is also something people should usually think through twice.